# PHP executando PYTHON

Tags: php, python, bash, shell

Estou tentando executar um script python pelo php, porém não executa o python.

Usei o código para testar:

```
$cmdResult = shell_exec("ls & /usr/local/bin/python2.7 --version & echo done");
```

Retornou:

```
done
LICENSE
example.py
```

Quando digito diretamente via shell:

```
[root@local folder]# /usr/local/bin/python2.7 --version
Python 2.7.6
```

Alguém tem alguma idéia?

Info adicional:

```
[root@local folder]# ls -all /usr/local/bin/py*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root apache      84 Jul 21 21:53 /usr/local/bin/pydoc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        24 Jul 21 21:43 /usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/local/bin/python2.7
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root apache 4669791 Jul 21 21:53 /usr/local/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root apache    1674 Jul 21 21:53 /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimenta o seguinte:

```
<?php

$comando = escapeshellcmd('./ficheiro_python.py');
$cmdResult = shell_exec($comando);
echo $cmdResult;

?>
```

Como linha "shebang" deverás ter o seguinte no ficheiro python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Também deverás ter permissões para executar esse ficheiro.

Testado com sucesso com o Ubuntu 16, PHP7.0 e python 2.7.

Comment: $comando = escapeshellcmd('/usr/local/bin/python2.7 --version');
$cmdResult = shell_exec($comando);
echo $cmdResult;
Não retornou a versão do Python.

Comment: @Hoppy pretendes executar um script python através de PHP ou executar um shell script para saber a versão python através de PHP?

Comment: Ambos não retornam resultado, acredito eu que se conseguir executar o comando '/usr/local/bin/python2.7 --version' poderei executar o python. Ja tentei da forma que apresentou. Quando executo no shell "./script.py ou /usr/local/bin/python2.7 --version" Ambos funcionam, porém quando é o PHP executando, não retorna resultado e não executa.

Comment: Experimenta utilizar a diretoria absoluta e dar todas as permissões ao ficheiro ".py"

Comment: $cmdResult = shell_exec("/var/www/html/example.py");
echo $cmdResult; Não retornou nada. como tenho 2 versões de python rodando, para executar o arquivo coloquei a linha "shebang" apontando pra versão correta: #!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

Comment: @Hoppy já descobri o problema. É necessário definir a passagem e não apenas o ficheiro como argumento da função "escapeshellcmd()". Já corrigi o script.

Comment: eu re-fiz o script em bash, não vou mais precisar me preocupar com python. x.x

Answer (score 0):

Você deve usar dois  E comerciais ("&&") ao invés de um apenas:

```
$cmdResult = shell_exec("ls && /usr/local/bin/python2.7 --version && echo done");
```