# Script em Python via PHP

Tags: php, python, linux

Estou tentando chamar um *script* feito em Python via browser com PHP. Esse *script* possui apenas um comando que serve para desligar minha Raspberry Pi.

O PHP está dessa forma:

```
<?php
 exec('sudo python /home/pi/Documents/Programa/Script.py');
?>
```

Script Python:

```
import os
os.system('sudo shutdown -r now')
```

Eu executei o programa em Python e PHP (via terminal) separadamente e os dois estão funcionando corretamente. Apenas quando chamo no browser que ele não executa. Sei que tem que alterar permissões de pastas e arquivos, mas não sei exatamente quais diretórios tenho que dar essas permissões pois sou iniciante no mundo do PHP e do linux. Eu já procurei em alguns outros site meios de fazer isso.

- [PHP executando PYTHON](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142520/php-executando-python)
- https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/Shell-Script/Como-executar-um-comando-em-shell-script-pelo-navegador

Comment: Por que você não executa o "shutdown" direto do PHP? Esse script nem tem nada de Python.

Comment: Olá jsbueno, obrigado por sua resposta. Você diz para eu colocar o comando "sudo shutdown -r now" direto no exec() do php? isso eu já fiz, também não funciona.

Comment: Não mostra nenhuma mensagem de erro? já viu no log do php ou do server?

Comment: Oi Júlio Neto, obrigado pela resposta. Eu não sei onde fica o log, vou procurar para ver se aparece alguma mensagem lá e volto com  a resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O php não tem permissão para desligar o computador. Ele roda com um usuário interno de serviço, (geralmente www-data), e esse usuário não tem permissão para executar o `sudo`.

Quando você roda com seu usuário, no terminal, funciona, porque o seu usuário tem a permissão de usar o `sudo`, mas ao fazer o php rodar o comando, vai falhar, porque o usuário que está rodando o servidor php não tem essa permissão.

Comment: Olá, eu entendi sua resposta, mas no caso não tem como eu dar essa permissão para o PHP? Eu vi em um dos links que citei ali em cima que você pode dar permissões a determinados arquivos e pastas, mas como não entendo muito de linux(raspbian) eu não sei exatamente como fazer.

Comment: @Q.Wesley Como o nosklo falou, é somente questão de permissão perante ao `sudo`. Se você adicionar o usuário do PHP, comumente `www-data` (confirme), à lista de *sudoers*, que são usuários com permissão ao `sudo`, você provavelmente conseguirá fazer algo do tipo. Mas antes de qualquer coisa, recomendo rever o comentário do [jsbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/331063/script-em-python-via-php#comment670193_331063), pois não temo motivo de fazer isso com o Python sendo que você pode executar o comando a partir do PHP.

Comment: @Q.Wesley, sim, o Anderson está certo. Você pode executar o shutdown direto do php, não precisa do python intermediário. A questão é configurar seu `sudo` - você pode fazer uma pergunta sobre como configurar o `sudo` no superuser.com (inglês)